# Does Denver International Airport display murals of conquering stormtroopers and dead children?

Tags: psychology, art, airport-security

Some people experience unease going through the airport, and it seems best to provide something soothing and uncontroversial to look at while walking to the aircraft .... like advertising.

Certainly I wouldn't expect to see:

**A dead child in a casket holding their bible**

[image: artwork allegedly on display at Denver International Airport]

**Soldier marching through ruins complete with gun, sword, and gas mask and civilian casualties**

[image: artwork allegedly on display at Denver International Airport]

[ my descriptions, as titles are uncited in source article ]

**Have these murals been on public display to travelers at the Denver International Airport?**

In http://www.bibliotecapleyades.net/esp_sociopol_denver.htm, which seems to contain conspiracy theory material, a large section is devoted to Denver International Airport.

Some claims, though repeated, about Denver's airport are so bizarre they seem like hoax material that no one would seriously believe:

- that the runways form a swastika [doesn't really look like it to me]
- that there is a secret base with underground buildings
- that murals depict what the conspirators plan to do with the rest of us

A google search for "denver international airport bizarre murals" turns ~50,000 hits and the first page shows a lot of similar material, much more than I would have expected.

I'm wondering if these murals were ever there, or are still there, or are off in a special art gallery near the terminal, so that regular travelers would not be greeted by the images as they changed planes.  If absent, then this may be a complete hoax.  Even if present, a reasonable explanation for the murals would be expected.

Even though Art in the United States is protected from government censorship by the First Amendment to the US Constitution as part of freedom of speech and press, I just can't imagine a busy airport sponsoring these kinds of disturbing images in the travel areas.

Comment: I don't really find that mural particularly disturbing, nor I have any problem in it being shown at an airport. Definitely better than those fake "smiling happy family" ads that you normally see.

Comment: Consistent with Chicano murals. The artist's statement is worth a read http://leotanguma.com/DIA-conspiracy-theories.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they are there.

The top image is part of:

[In Peace and Harmony with Nature
Artist: Leo Tanguma | Location: Jeppesen Terminal, Level 5](http://www.flydenver.com/artdetailpage?URI=tcm:8-34021&PURI=tcm:8-34002)

The second image is part of a two frame mural titled:

The Children of the World Dream of Peace (right side) which is also by Leo Tanguma.

It does not mentioned on the DIA website where the right hand panel is located, but it does list the left hand panel.

There are plenty of conspiracy theories around the airport and the images themselves which you don't specifically ask about, but the artist does [address them on his website](http://leotanguma.com/DIA-conspiracy-theories.html).

> To the many people who have viewed or MAY view my DIA murals in the future, I wish to explain their thematic subjects and their meanings. I do so after seeing repeated postings on the internet suggesting the most outrageous and sinister interpretations of my murals by conspiracy theorists. Those ridiculous assertions, however, have caused confusion among some and it is for their benefit that I write these lines